# Агрегации в mongo

Tags: mongodb

Начинаю изучать mongo, ни как не могу понять что делаю не так. Пытаюсь сделать простую агрегацию через $lookup

есть две коллекции productmodels и reviewmodels
пытаюсь получить все *продукты* и относяшиеся к ним *отзывы* запрос вида

```
db.productmodels.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "reviewmodels",
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'productId',
            as: 'review'
        }
    }
])
```

в коллекции продуктов лежит 1 продукт - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в коллекции отзывов лежит 3 отзыва к этому продукту (productId) - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате запроса получаю пустой массив отзывов по этому продукту (review) - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй в Компас (там есть конструктор агрегаций) сделать аналогичный запрос. На вид у тебя все нормально... У меня вот такой работает нормально `{
  from: 'img',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'owner.id',
  as: 'img'
}`

Comment: Проверь все идентификаторы - может где в буковках ошибся...

Comment: Выложите в виде текста ваши коллекции. Чтобы любой, кто хочет помочь, мог скопировать их. Ещё можно [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) подготовить.